# What can a malicious user do with a shared android tablet on a corporate network via connected to corp WIFI?

Tags: network, wifi, android

We are deploying android tablets with a shared pin for users in an office.
If the device was stolen or in the hands of a hacker, what can a hacker do on the network (realistically)?

Android does NOT have a command prompt so therefore would not able to run commands like Windows.
We are looking to disable Google play to prevent download of any unauthorized apps.
The tablets do not have USB ports.
There will be access to the internet.
No company data will be stored on the device.

The device will connect to the corporate WIFI(WPA2) using the wifi password and there will no further authentication.

The device will be used to access 1 corporate app which connects to internal servers.

We understand that shared PINs brings with it the problem of non-repudiation between internal users.

What should i be worried about with an unauthorized user/hacker?

Comment: As long as the hacker doesn't know its screen lock code, there's nothing much can be done with it except for receiving calls, messages and notifications at locked screen.

Comment: @defalt what can hacker do to a corporate network if he/she knows the PIN?

Comment: It can browse intranet and search for employees profile for social engineering. The attack vector is dependent on the corporate security.